# LocalizationService formatDateTime method is not displaying correct time in European Time format

Tags: lightning-aura-components, datetime, lightning-inputfield

I am not getting expected output in time value. I am passing value as **20190619131800Z** through query parameter and trying to format it according to Salesforce User Timezone. I am using **lightning:inputField** in lightning component to display this DateTime value. Need urgent help around this.

> component.find("verificationDate").set("v.value",
>   $A.localizationService.formatDateTime(component.get("v.SF_VerificationDate"),'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss-hh:mm'));

Expected Output- 19.06.2019 13.18;
Actual Output- 19.06.2019 04.00

Answer (score 1):

In your Lightning Page, go to your Javascript Console. and paste the following snippet

`eval("$A.localizationService.formatDateTime('20190619131800Z ','YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss-hh:mm');");`

It will give output as `"Invalid Date"`

Now coming to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_format_dates.htm).

> The date parameter can be a String, Number, or most typically a
>   JavaScript Date. If you provide a String value, use **ISO 8601** format to
>   avoid parsing warnings.

`20190619131800Z` is not in [ISO 8601](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html) format.

You have to convert `20190619131800Z` into `2019-06-19T13:18:00Z` for localization service to work. You can do that using string manipulation